# Amazon AWS IOS SDK: How to download ALL files in a bucket without naming them individually

Tags: ios, download, amazon-s3

I upload and download files from AWS S3.  Trouble is, I am having to specify each file by its name.  I want to be able to download all the files in a specific bucket (directory) without naming them individually.

I currently use this code:

```
    s3Client = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:ACCESS_KEY withSecretKey:SECRET_KEY];              
    getObjectRequest = [[S3GetObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:arrayName withBucket:bucketName];
    getObjectResponse = [s3Client getObject:getObjectRequest];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
S3ListObjectsRequest *listObjectRequest = [[[S3ListObjectsRequest alloc] initWithName:"YourBucket"] autorelease];

S3ListObjectsResponse *listObjectResponse = [[AmazonClientManager s3] listObjects:listObjectRequest];

S3ListObjectsResult *listObjectsResults = listObjectResponse.listObjectsResult;

for (S3ObjectSummary *objectSummary in listObjectsResults.objectSummaries) {
    NSLog(@"Bucket Contents %@ " ,[objectSummary key]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ranga.  Since asking this I discovered AWS SimpleDB, which is a better solution.  Appreciate your help.